# Load C structure from string

Tags: c, file

My situation is as follows. I obtain FILE * pointer. I know it can point to FILE type that does not support seek (can be PIPE). So to make things easier I thought of loading parts of the file to memory as a string buffer.

The problem is, that my file contains, next to some other stuff, C structures, that I need to load to memory. And so far, everything I have tried had failed.

Most promising seemed to be fmemopen, but when I added it to my code I got

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fmemopen’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
stream = fmemopen (buffer, p_header.bytes, "r");
```

warning and that is certainly nothing I want. It remained implicit declared even though I added stdio.h include.

Can anything be done about that? Can I somehow create something of FILE * type in memory so I can call fread on it?
Or is there a way how to read structure from string?

I have used fread as follows:

```
fread(&var_of_type_love_struct_t, sizeof(love_struct_t), 1, myfile);
```

Comment: Look at the man page for fmemopen, it will tell you about some #defines. Assuming that your system even has it. In any cases, 'memcpy' is the same thing as fread from fmemopen.

Comment: Your question keeps describing a `FILE*`, but you don't show your `fopen` call.  **Post More Code**

Answer (score 3):

The warning about `fmemopen` is that the compiler didn't find the prototype, add

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

**before** including all the headers, or, if using GCC, add `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to the options.